# Dell Inspirion 1525 Windows 7 64-bit Bluetooth internet connection via Android Phone bluetooth

Tags: internet, bluetooth, connection

I have an Android Phone with Bluetooth, now my Dell laptop has a Bluetooth module. I have been able to connect to the internet via my cell phone -
I have a Verizon Wireless USB760 Modem (CDMA direct connect device).

Can I connect two devices to the cell phone Bluetooth for internet connections? Or will I need some software to do the connection?

Can I take the USB760 Modem device and pair it with my cell phone for a internet connection with another computer (Dell E310)?

Comment: Please try not to abuse upper-case https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling.

Answer (score 0):

Turn Bluetooth ON for both laptop and cell phone.

On your laptop: Control Panel > Bluetooth > Settings > Options > Enable Bluetooth Discovery and Connection. 
Start > Devices and Printers > Add a device > Select your android phone

On my S5 running android 5.0 I go to Settings > More Networks > Tethering > Enable Bluetooth tethering.

Some carriers may charge fees for this